# ASP.NET MVC Kendo UI Treemap - Data?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik

Does anybody know how to set the data for the Kendo Treemap in ASP.NET MVC?
I have a list like this (C# List):

```
 Item   |  Count
------------------
Item 1  |   4
Item 2  |   7
Item 3  |   2
Item 4  |   9
```

Here is the cshtml part form the demo-site (http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/treemap):

```
@(Html.Kendo().TreeMap()
      .Name("treeMap")
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
          .Read(read => read
              .Action("_PopulationUSA", "TreeMap")
          )
          .Model(m => m.Children("Items"))
      )
      .ValueField("Value")
      .TextField("Name")
      .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:600px; font-size: 12px;" })
)
```

Where can i set the values?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good question. That demo does not show the controller method used to populate the data. I bet it is using the `HierarchicalDataSource` which supports any custom Name/Value class with a self referencing collection property. I think you will need to download the demo to see what the controller in the demo is doing, however, I will take my best shot at it for you. The server binding is actually quite simple, once you know the signature. Here, I am assuming the Items property is the recursive relation between parent and children. In this case, country - state - city.

There is a jQuery example using a `HierarchicalDataSource` [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/treemap#methods), however, you do not need to use that method.

If your data is not hierarchical, you can just send over a simple list of name/value pairs and removed the Model property in your TreeMap ui configuration.

The Model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public int Value{ get; set; }
    List<MyModel> Items{get;set;}
}
```

The Controller Method :

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]
    public ActionResult GetMyTreeMapData(int someID, [DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        List<MyModel> items = new List<MyModel>();
        items=SomeMethodToRecursivelyFillYourParentAndChildren();
        return Json(items.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

The UI Binding :

```
@(Html.Kendo().TreeMap()
      .Name("treeMap")
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
          .Read(read => read
              .Action("GetMyTreeMapData", "MyController")
          )
          .Model(m => m.Children("Items"))
      )
      .ValueField("Value")
      .TextField("Name")
      .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:600px; font-size: 12px;" })
)
```

Comment: This is what i need - Thanks a lot!!